# How to manually update Relay store without querying server?

Tags: relayjs

Let's say I have some data that I obtained through a non-graphql endpoint for example from third party server (firebase).

How do I put the data into the local relay store?
Is there an easy way to add / edit / overwrite data to relay store directly without going through query or mutation?

Comment: Did you find a way todo this?!

Answer (score 3):

A non public [RelayStoreData](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/store/RelayStoreData.js) field is accessible from the `Relay.Store` instance and it gives you direct access to the records contained in the store. I haven't done anything with this myself but you could try modifying the cache directly like this:

`RelayStore._storeData._cachedStore._records[recordId][fieldName]=newValue`

Answer (score 0):

I would use relay without a server, defining your graphql schema locally and doing your API requests from your graphql schema the same way you would query a database in your schema.

https://github.com/relay-tools/relay-local-schema